# Can I use php without REST style web service protocol to create server of pass ?

Tags: ios, rest, passbook

I am new in REST. I want to create server of passes. Do I have to use REST or not ?

Comment: What is a 'server of passes'?

Comment: is this your question?

Comment: I want update pass by push notification.

Comment: I create pass already !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you need to build a REST web service if you want to be update Apple Passbook Passes.

> A REST-style web service protocol is used to communicate with your
>   server about changes to passes, and to fetch the latest version of a
>   pass when it has changed.

See the [Passbook Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) for the full specification.